# C++ writing strange symbols instead of characters

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, iteration, fstream

New to this forum so I hope my formatting is okay.

The following is meant to iterate over the strings (`sections`) in a .txt, then run a function `nuc(`) on each character in the string (`section`). `nuc()` on each character either adds the character to the string called `fragment`, or adds a period `"."`. If `nuc` is executed on the end of a string, it should write fragment to the text file "fragments.txt". Because `nuc` is executed within itself, it starts by shortening the fragment to the position on which `nuc` is being executed.

Unfortunately when I execute the code it doesn't seem to write the characters, instead writing bizarre symbols (rotated L's or playing card suits). Should I use something other than a string? This is essentially translated from python so you can imagine the oversights I'm capable of.

I've learned most of this over the last two days so I apologize in advance if its a really silly oversight. I suspect it may be due to the way I've initialized my `nuc` function, or the way I've called it.

I appreciate any help in advance. I suspect my code is painful to look at.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

ifstream sections("sections.txt");
ofstream fragments("fragments.txt");
string fragment;


void nuc(string section, int position)
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {
        fragment.resize(position);
        cout << i << endl;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fragment += ".";
        }
        else if (i == 1)
        {
            fragment += position;
        }

        try
        {
            section.at(position + 1);
            nuc(section, position + 1);
        }

        catch (exception out_of_range)
        {
            fragment += "\n";
            fragments << fragment;
        }

        cout << fragment << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string section;
    int pos = 0;

    while (getline(sections, section))
    {
        nuc(section, pos);
    }

    sections.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: 
alright i got it to run by switching fragment += position to fragment += section.get(position) (smh). Now it seems I can fragment longer strings than I could in python, but it still takes very long. Can anyone offer any recommendations to optimize the code to make it run faster, e.g. if using iterators rather than strings to get(position) might make it run faster? Otherwise perhaps a resource that could help me learn about optimizing code with these basic functions?

Comment: Lets take the very first call to `nuc` from the `main` function, when `position == 0`. What character do you think `0` is? I don't know of *any* encoding where `0 == '0'`, if that's what you think. Especially not true in [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) (which is the most common character encoding).

Comment: Can you give an example of "sections.txt" and what the resulting "fragments.txt" should look like? Also I suggest that you run this code in a debugger and single step through each line.

Comment: @someprogrammerdude that's an issue with the translation, in python str[0] refers to the first character in the string str. I see my mistake here, I was initially working with position as an iterator, so i could, at least in a while loop, refer to the first character using the value of the first position. Now that i abandoned the loop and changed to ints i forgot to go from int to str[int]. So is there a way to refer to the char at position (int) x of (str) section? if so, what value would the first position have?

Comment: @Rudi while testing, sections just say "hello" on the first line and "world" on the second. the fragments are easier to show with a shorter word. The word "bad" should produce fragments "b.." ".a." "..d" "ba." ".ad" "b.d" "..." and "bad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see lots of weird characters is because of

```
fragment += position;
```

`fragment` is a `string`, `position` is an `int`. When you add `int` to `string` it is treated as a `char` created from `int` code, and many of those `chars` at the start of ASCII table are not even printable. [See for yourself](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: My gosh what a ridiculous mistake. Is there a way to use an int to refer to the character at a particular position in a string? For example in python: str bad = "bad", b[0] would refer to "b", b[1] would refer to "a", etc. would it be faster to use an iterator than an int? if an int can even refer to particular character...

Comment: @Kama Same in C++ you could `section[position]` to get the `char` at position `position` but it is better to use `size_t` instead of `int`.

Comment: @Killzone_Kid would it execute faster with size_t instead of int? Or is it better for another reason?

Comment: @Kama All `std::` containers that can have index use `size_t`, including `std::string`. You might get conversion warnings.